# Second Wordpress Ajax not firing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Hi there I am trying use some wordpress ajax my first ajax request works fine but the second one does not. Can some one please tell me why this is happening

Works fine:

**PHP**

```html
//Add Students Details to DB
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {

 $fName = $_POST['fName'];
 $lName = $_POST['lName'];
 $dob = $_POST['dob'];
 $gender = $_POST['gender'];
 $diet = $_POST['diet'];

 $current_id = get_current_user_id();


 global $wpdb;

 $result = $wpdb->insert( 
  'wp_students', 
  array( 
   'ID' => NULL, 
   'first_name' => $fName,
   'last_name' => $lName,
   'birthdate' => $dob,
   'gender' => $gender,
   'dietary_requirements' => $diet,
   'user_id' => $current_id
  )
 );

 echo json_encode($result);
 wp_die();
}
```

**JS**

```js
var data_value = {
                    action: 'my_action',
                    fName: $(acc[i]).find('input.fName').val(),
                    lName: $(acc[i]).find('input.lName').val(),
                    dob: $(acc[i]).find('input.dob').val(),
                    gender: $(acc[i]).find('select.gender').val(),
                    diet: $(acc[i]).find('textarea.diet_req').val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    data: data_value,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        if (msg == false) {
                            $('#insert_status').html('<strong><span style="color: red;">Error: </span></strong>Details Have Not Been Updated');
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        var i = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                        alert(i.Message);
                    }
                });
```

Does not work:

**PHP**

```html
//Delete Students Details
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_delete', 'my_action_callback_delete' );
function my_action_callback_delete() {
 echo 'here';
 global $wpdb;

 $result = $wpdb->delete( 'wp_students', array( 'usesr_id' => get_current_user_id()) );
 echo json_encode($result);
 wp_die();
}
```

**JS**

```js
var value = {
                    action: 'my_delete'
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    data: value,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        if (msg == false) {
                            $('#insert_status').html('<strong><span style="color: red;">Error: </span></strong>Details Have Not Been Updated');
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        var i = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                        alert(i.Message);
                    }
                });
```

If you could help me would be great. Wordpress Ajax is not a straight forward as normal ajax.

Comment: did you get any respons? like 0 or -1? are you firing the request only for logged-in user? try checking https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action) and see if you're doing the correct way

Comment: Hey @silver I followed the wordpress codex. I am not receiving any response at all it is strange.

Comment: are you running the code for non-logged-in user? did you try adding the ajax hook for non logged in request ```add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_delete', 'my_action_callback_delete' );``` 
if that still doesn't work then the problem is in your js code.

Comment: No the user has to be logged in to be able to access this page. It is a part of there account page.

Comment: your ajax request might have run and it could be that your function doesn't return anything, add ```wp_die('Condolence');``` or check your network tab and verify that your request is firing or not, if its not firing then double check your js code,

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you just have a typo in your delete function?

`'usesr_id' => get_current_user_id()`

should probably be

`'user_id' => get_current_user_id()`

```html
//Delete Students Details
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_delete', 'my_action_callback_delete' );
function my_action_callback_delete() {
 echo 'here';
 global $wpdb;

 $result = $wpdb->delete( 'wp_students', array( 'usesr_id' => get_current_user_id()) );
 echo json_encode($result);
 wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for spoting the typo I fixed it ! But it it still does not work. i does not enter the php function at all

Comment: How do you know that? What method are you using to determine there is no response?

Comment: Use your browser's developer console with the Network tab and tell us what the response is to your call.